# create static android broadcast reciever programatically

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Hi is there a way to programatically create a static broadcast reciever programatically?

From the docs it says there are two ways to use recievers:

1. Register through manifest(static and can be used when app is not running)
2. Register through application Context(Dynamic and can only be used as long as the activity/app is running)

I could not find a way to register programatically a static receiver. Is there not a way to do this?

Comment: What would you like to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot modify the manifest at runtime. Hence, you cannot register a "static" receiver at runtime.

You *can* enable and disable a manifest-registered receiver at runtime. Have the `android:enabled` attribute on your `<receiver>` element be set to whatever you want your starting state to be (e.g., `false` for disabled). Then, use `PackageManager` and `setComponentEnabledSetting()` to change that enabled status at runtime. A disabled receiver will not respond to broadcasts.

Answer (score 1):

```
//For dynamic execution
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        reciever = new IncomingCallReciever();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
        registerReceiver(reciever, filter);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (reciever != null) {
            unregisterReceiver(reciever);
            reciever = null;
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```